# "An error occured while executing doInBackground()" after LRX210 update (Nexus 5)

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, android-5.0-lollipop

I was just wondering if anyone else is having this issue.
I have two Nexus 5's, one running 5.0 LPX13D (dev preview), and the other running 5.0 LRX210 (official release).
In my application, I call a method call getFiles() from the AsyncTasks doInBackground() method.
On the phone running LPX13D, this works fine, and the application runs perfectly.
However on the phone running LRX210, the app crashes at the line `"File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();"` with the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`

It only happens on the phone running LRX210. And from what i can see, the method is not accessing the UI thread, so it should be working fine.
If anyone else is having issue, and has found a fix, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The full code for the AsyncTask is below.

Thanks in advance
Corey :)

```
    public class UpdateDataSet extends AsyncTask<List, String, List> {

        @Override
        protected List doInBackground(List... params) {
            getFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Constants.DIRECTORY);
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List recordingList) {
            super.onPostExecute(recordingList);
            rAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        public void getFiles(String directoryName){
            File directory = new File(directoryName);
            Log.v("FilesListFragment", "getFiles();");
            File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();

            for(File file: fileList){
                if(file.isFile() && !files.contains(file)){
                    files.add(file);
                }
                /*
                else if(file.isDirectory()){
                    files(file.getAbsoluteFile(), false);
                }
                */
            }
            updateRecordingsList();
        }

        public void updateRecordingsList(){

            for(int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
                boolean fileFound = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < recordingsList.size(); j++) {
                    if (recordingsList.get(j).getFile().equals(files.get(i))) {
                        fileFound = true;
                    }
                }
                if(fileFound != true){
                    recordingsList.add(new Recording(files.get(i), new Date(files.get(i).lastModified())));
                }
            }
            if(rAdapter != null) {
                Log.i("FileListFragment", "notifyDataSetChanged()");
            }
            //Collections.sort(recordingsList);


        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Here is the full logat filtered to my specific package name:

```
11-13 20:00:19.753    3539-3559/com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
11-13 20:00:19.762    3539-3539/com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
11-13 20:00:19.846    3539-3560/com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift V/FilesListFragment﹕ getFiles();
11-13 20:00:19.851    3539-3560/com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift, PID: 3539
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
            at com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift.FilesListFragment$UpdateDataSet.getFiles(FilesListFragment.java:124)
            at com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift.FilesListFragment$UpdateDataSet.doInBackground(FilesListFragment.java:107)
            at com.bacon.corey.audiotimeshift.FilesListFragment$UpdateDataSet.doInBackground(FilesListFragment.java:103)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Can you post full logcat?

Comment: I will edit my comment now. Corey :)

Comment: It says NPE on FilesListFragment.java:124!

Comment: might directory be null in `File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();` for some reason?

Comment: Hey, You were right. For some reason fileList is null. I will go and hava a go debugging it, and see what i can find. It is strange that it is only happening on the newer android version though. Thanks for your help, Corey :)

Comment: May be some issue with new File(directoryName) call.. good luck

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `fileList` in the following line is evaluated to `null`:

```java
File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();
```

If we check that in Javadoc (see: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles())), we can see that:

> If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null.

Thus, the first thing that I would do, would be to debug the app and lookup following lines:

```java
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Constants.DIRECTORY;
```

and

```java
File directory = new File(directoryName);
File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();
```

If the path name is correct, there might be other reasons why reference to a file is not created, for example:

- `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the primary
  external storage directory. This directory may not currently be
  accessible if it has been mounted by the user, has been removed from
  the device, or some other problem has happened. You can determine its
  current state with `getExternalStorageState()`.
- On devices with multiple users (as described by `UserManager`), each
  user has their own isolated external storage. Applications only have
  access to the external storage for the user they're running as. In
  devices with multiple "external" storage directories, this directory
  represents the "primary" external storage that the user will interact
  with. Access to secondary storage is available through.
- Finally, writing to this path requires the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
  permission, and starting in read access requires the
  `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, which is automatically granted if
  you hold the write permission.

For more info see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html